# Difference between 2>&1 <command> and <command> 2>&1

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I have the following two invocations of a function in bash, which I'm piping to another function which captures the error output:

`>&2 log_stdout | log_err`

`log_stdout >&2 | log_err`

**Is there any semantic difference between the two?**

Edit: The suggested duplicate, while having an *awesome* community wiki, does not provide an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I reckoned “They can appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.” in the suggested duplicate did answer your question.

Comment: @StephenKitt: Yes, that just didn't seem clear enough for me at the time, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent.

The relative order of redirections may matter, but their position with respect to the command does not.